# How to test whether stereo cameras is synchronization?

Tags: stereo, synchronization, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a stereo camera consist of two digital cameras. I want to test whether the left and the right images is synchronization. Are there some tools or nodes which have this function? (PS:I can get the timestemp of the images)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53415/how-to-test-whether-stereo-cameras-is-synchronization?/) by [monsterkappa](https://answers.ros.org/users/1863/monsterkappa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One simple method is recording some image messages using [rosbag](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#record) and viewing them with [rxbag](http://ros.org/wiki/rxbag). The rxbag GUI will let you zoom in on the message timestamps, making it easy to see how close they are for the two cameras.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1